# Why java method name should not contain underscore?

Tags: java, pmd

I am using **PMD** for checking java coding violation.
I am writing automation test cases, and given method name like this:

```
public void testCaseMethod_4_2_16(){
   //some implementation 
}
```

where 4_2_16 is test case number 4.2.16

and when I check for **PMD** violation it is showing **method name should not contain underscore**, and this violation is shown as **blocker** according to PMD rules.
So here are my question:

- Why method name should not contain underscore is define as a **blocker** or **PMD error**?
- What kind of PMD violation we should avoid and
- What kind of violation we should try to fixed?

As for my understanding at least we should avoid first two level of violation shown by PMD.
Any help on the PMD rule will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: I don't know why, though I always use *camelcase* for methods and *underscores* for variables. Why? So it's easier to distinguish variables from methods.

Comment: @Vallentin aren't the braces at the end of a method sufficient?

Comment: @Vallentin Underscores in variables only for `FINAL_VARIABLE_NAMES`! Apart from that, it's "only" a convention (the original naming conventions document is gone, but see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html for examples)

Comment: but I think it give us more information about test case if I put test case number as 4_2_16 at the end of method rather then just writing 4216

Comment: @Marco13 "final variables" are usually referenced as "constants" instead (in Java).

Comment: @Sanjay you are right IMO. I also often use underscores in tests to make the name more readable. BTW: I think it makes more sense to add the name of the test-case instead of the number. When you just add the test-case-number, you need the test-document to get an idea of what the test does.

Comment: @Sanjay PMD is a tool that can and should be configured to suit your needs. If you/your colleagues/your project just can't live with `_` in method names, then leave that PMD rule as is and fix your code. If you think that you need `_` than you should just configure the rule accordingly - disable it or change the name pattern.

Comment: @Andy I mainly program in C++ currently, and well you don't always have to use parenthesis at the end of a function name. So thereby using underscores in a function name, I could easily confuse a function with a variable.

Comment: This is a traditional naming convention.  some people say "It ars easilish with no underscore".  as you may have noticed, I dont have much respect for that belief; it is not easier, just traditional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a standard that has been set so that people can easily read each other's code, therefore making code more maintainable.

The quote below is from Oracle's website on [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/namingconventions-139351.html):

> - 80% of the lifetime cost of a piece of software goes to maintenance.
> - Hardly any software is maintained for its whole life by the original    author.
> - Code conventions improve the readability of the software, allowing    engineers to understand new code more quickly and thoroughly.

Comment: +1 for the 80% lifetime cost. that's one of the most intelligent things that are said about software

Answer (score 5):

Java prefers *camelCase* notation. [Java code conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) say that you should try to avoid underscores in method or variable name whenever it is possible.

In your case PMD's default prioritization fails. This rule should be on a "nice-to-have" level, but definitely not a blocker issue.

I would recommend you to use [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/), which did a re-prioritization of PMD's rules, which works better is most cases. The rule you found is just on Major level (below levels Blocker and Critical).

[image: Naming Conventions rule in Sonar]

If you are still not satisfied with the results, you can use the [SourceMeter plugin for SonarQube](http://sourcemeter.com), which has a different (possible better) prioritization of PMD rules as well.

Answer (score 3):

Although there are lots of opinions out there, I like to separate quality-assurance for production and the one for test code.

If that is not possible for whatever reason, I'd rather deactivate (most of) the warnings for test-code. I think it is not worth the time making the test-code pretty (and underscores in method names is just styling to me), while there are serious warnings for the production code left open.

Comment: Yes I told reviewer that it should be ignore. but his question was why it is declare as **blocker** you should have a valid reason.

Comment: There are 2 reasons: 1) it's test-code 2) it's only about styling . These are reasonable arguments for me, and I'm also doing code-reviews regularly. IF the PMD-default is 'blocker', it's wrongly classified IMO. (wanted to check the default on the PMD-homepage, which is currently not reachable...)

Comment: But that are the rule set given by the them , and if I will make change in PMD rule set by them, is it proper way to to change default rule set,and modify them according to our use. and then what is the use of checking PMD violation.

Answer (score 0):

In java underscore is allowed while naming identifiers. I don't know why PMD is showing violation but you can just deactivate the warnings and go on. UNDERSCORE is allowed in java while naming identifiers.

I think it may help you...